# How to make complicated multicolumn binding of my two tables?

Tags: r, dataframe, binding

I have a single column dataframe with column type with all possible "types":

```
comment       type

used         enter 
used         open
used         close
used         update
not_used     delete
```

I get dataframe from my database. But in that dataframe, not all "types" might be. Here is example of that table:

```
ID    date            type           value
a1    2020-09-01       enter          18
a1    2020-09-01       close          15
a1    2020-09-02       enter          4
a2    2020-09-01       close          10
b1    2020-09-02       update         10
```

As you see ID a1 has only two types: enter and close. a2 has only close, b1 has only update.

I want to bind these two tables in that way, so "types" which were not in my table have value zero for each ID and date. So, how to bind these two tables to get this:

```
comment            ID    date            type           value
used               a1    2020-09-01       enter          18
used               a1    2020-09-01       open           0
used               a1    2020-09-01       close          15
used               a1    2020-09-01       update         0
not_used           a1    2020-09-01       delete         0
used               a1    2020-09-02       enter          4
used               a1    2020-09-02       open           0
used               a1    2020-09-02       close          0
used               a1    2020-09-02       update         0
not_used           a1    2020-09-02       delete         0
used               a2    2020-09-01       enter          0
used               a2    2020-09-01       open           0
used               a2    2020-09-01       close          10
used               a2    2020-09-01       update         0
not_used           a2    2020-09-01       delete         0
used               b1    2020-09-01       enter          0
used               b1    2020-09-01       open           0
used               b1    2020-09-01       close          0
used               b1    2020-09-01       update         10
not_used           b1    2020-09-01       delete         0
```

As you see, I also kept column "comment". How could i do that?

Thise doesn't keep column "comment":

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 %>%
  mutate(type = factor(type, levels = df1$type)) %>%
  group_by(ID, date) %>%
  complete(type, fill = list(value = 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
new <- df2 %>%
  mutate(type = factor(type, levels = df1$type)) %>%
  group_by(ID, date) %>%
  complete(type, fill = list(value = 0)) %>%
  left_join(df1)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 5
# Groups:   ID, date [4]
   ID    date       type   value comment 
   <chr> <chr>      <chr>  <dbl> <chr>   
 1 a1    2020-09-01 enter     18 used    
 2 a1    2020-09-01 open       0 used    
 3 a1    2020-09-01 close     15 used    
 4 a1    2020-09-01 update     0 used    
 5 a1    2020-09-01 delete     0 not_used
 6 a1    2020-09-02 enter      4 used    
 7 a1    2020-09-02 open       0 used    
 8 a1    2020-09-02 close      0 used    
 9 a1    2020-09-02 update     0 used    
10 a1    2020-09-02 delete     0 not_used
11 a2    2020-09-01 enter      0 used    
12 a2    2020-09-01 open       0 used    
13 a2    2020-09-01 close     10 used    
14 a2    2020-09-01 update     0 used    
15 a2    2020-09-01 delete     0 not_used
16 b1    2020-09-02 enter      0 used    
17 b1    2020-09-02 open       0 used    
18 b1    2020-09-02 close      0 used    
19 b1    2020-09-02 update    10 used    
20 b1    2020-09-02 delete     0 not_used
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one easy solution, would be to perform a `full_join` after

```
df2 %>%
  mutate(type = factor(type, levels = df1$type)) %>%
  group_by(ID, date) %>%
  complete(type, fill = list(value = 0)) %>% 
  full_join(df1, by = "type")
```